# Vuejs databinding on image source not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following component where I read data from Indexeddb (ArrayBuffer) and use it as source for an image. When the parent component uses this component, only the last formUpload gets it's dataSource set. My console.log's tells me that the data is there, the URL.createobjecturl is succesfully created, I can open them in devtools and see the images, but they are not assigned as the source of the image. Any ideas?

```
<div class="ui grid segment" v-if="formData.Uploads.length > 0">
    <div class="four wide column" v-for="upload in formData.Uploads" style="position:relative;">
        <formUpload :upload="upload"></formUpload>
    </div>
</div>

Vue.component("formUpload", {
    props: ["upload"],
    template: `
        <div class="ui fluid image">
            <a class="ui green left corner label">
                <i class="add icon"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="ui red right corner label" v-on:click="removeUpload(upload)">
                <i class="remove icon"></i>
            </a>
            <img style="width:100%;" :src="dataSource" />
            <div class="ui blue labels" v-if="upload.tags.length > 0" style="margin-top:5px;">
                <image-tag v-for="tag in upload.tags" :tagtext="tag" :key="tag" :upload="upload.id" v-on:deletetag="deletetag"></image-tag>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    data: function () {
        return {
            dataSource: undefined
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        _this = this;

        imageStore.getItem(_this.upload.imageId).then(function (result) {

            console.log("Data gotten", result.data);

            var dataView = new DataView(result.data);
            var blob = new Blob([dataView], { type: result.type });

            console.log("Data transformed", blob);

            _this.dataSource = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            console.log("DataUrl", _this.dataSource);

        });

    },
    methods: {
        removeUpload: function (upload) {
            console.log("removeUpload");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You need a key.https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: @RoyJ - thanks - I actually tried doing this earlier, but it didn't work, but now I found out why. It's not enough to create the key on the component, it should also be included in props to work. Could you create an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, [you need a key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key).

> When Vue is updating a list of elements rendered with `v-for`, it by
> default uses an “in-place patch” strategy. If the order of the data
> items has changed, instead of moving the DOM elements to match the
> order of the items, Vue will simply patch each element in-place and
> make sure it reflects what should be rendered at that particular
> index. This is similar to the behavior of `track-by="$index"` in Vue
> 1.x.

> This default mode is efficient, but only suitable **when your list render output does not rely on child component state or temporary DOM
> state (e.g. form input values).**
> [...]
> It is recommended to provide a key with v-for whenever possible, unless the iterated DOM content is simple, or you are intentionally relying on the default behavior for performance gains.

This is a fairly common "gotcha" which should be helped by the fact that

> **In 2.2.0+, when using `v-for` with a component, a `key` is now required.**

Comment: Strange thing is, that I didn't get any warning or anything and I'm using version 2.2.2